# React, Web3.js & Metaplex: Unable to import `programs.metadata.Metadata` from @metaplex/js

Tags: node.js, web3js, solana-web3js, metaplex

## Issue

Attempting to follow the 'your first request' example here: https://docs.metaplex.com/sdk/js/getting-started#your-first-request

The module referred to in the examples doesn't contain the data needed.

For context, I am using this example to develop the solution explained at step 5 of these instructions: https://gist.github.com/creativedrewy/9bce794ff278aae23b64e6dc8f10e906

## Steps to replicate

Step 1) I install the `@metaplex/js` package via: `yarn add @metaplex/js`

Step 2) I import `programs` from the module by placing `import { programs } from '@metaplex/js';`.

Step 3) I attempt to unpack `Metadata` from programs via: `const { Metadata } = programs.metadata;`

At this stage, if I execute `npm run start` or `yarn run start` I see the error that the property `Metadata` of `programs.metadata` is undefined. When I look in `node_modules/@metaplex/js/` I see that the error is correct.

The only mention of metadata in the module is the function used to lookup metadata once you have the URL. The stage I am at is attempting to retrieve the URL, so this package is not useful, despite being the only one referred to in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue, I created an empty react app and added the following dependencies to my `package.json` file:

```
  "@metaplex/js": "^1.1.1",
  "@solana/spl-token": "^0.1.8",
  "@solana/web3.js": "^1.24.1",
```

I then ran `npm install` inside the app's root directory.

Inside `App.js` (or `index.js` if you did not use create-react-app), I unpacked `Metadata` directly from the metaplex package with the following line, placed at the top of the file:

```
import { Metadata } from '@metaplex/js';
```

Beneath all the imports, I added the following code (an edited version of the code from the example in the original question):

```
const connection = new Connection('devnet');
const tokenPublicKey = 'Gz3vYbpsB2agTsAwedtvtTkQ1CG9vsioqLW3r9ecNpvZ';

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const ownedMetadata = await Metadata.load(connection, tokenPublicKey);
    console.log(ownedMetadata);
  } catch {
    console.log('Failed to fetch metadata');
  }
};
```

In my implementation, I'm using a button inside my `App()` function, instead of calling `run()` directly like in the example:

```
<button
  onClick={run}
>
  GALLERY
</button>
```

Now, when clicking the button, I correctly see the metadata JSON displayed in the console.

Comment: How did `import { Metadata } from '@metaplex/js';` fix your issue? You don't seem to be referencing it in this code. Can you post the full App.js or a codepen? This could clear things up.

Comment: I am also having this problem. It doesn't seem like import { Metadata} should change anything since you are calling it with progams.metadata.Metadata (you didn't even have to import it, it's not being used). If you could explain how you solved this, w/the code shown, that would help me right now.

Comment: @jumar my bad I just made a mistake copying the example code over (my actual code is more complex so not suitable to use here). I just updated my answer. You use `Metadata.load()` directly as opposed to `programs.metadata.Metadata.load()`. If you're still stuck then we can open a chat and I'll help figure it out.